# What is index.html.save file?

Tags: apache2

In my `www/html/sitemane` folder I have found `index.html.save` file.

What is this file? I did not create it. Does apache has created it? For what purpose?

Comment: It could be that your 3rd party software editor or someone might have created a file as backup and renamed it as `index.html.save`. rename that file back to `index.html` and open the page to see and then revert it back. as it could be a temporary file created by system.

Comment: @shaze. Maybe sublime text has created it?

Comment: It could be, yes, I use "Brackets" for web frontend work, and use "SublimeText3"  `cpp` for backend. Not to say theres anything wrong with any of them, just happen to use so that i dont have to keep clicking different tabs for different project works. Easier to alt+tab them.

Comment: Also you must know, 'Brackets' have really great extensions for Web development work & its free.

Comment: @Shaze Add your first comment as answer for this question.

Comment: @Shaze _“rename that file back to index.html”_ I guess the `index.html` file is kept, so blindly running `mv index.html.save index.html` could remove the correct version.

Comment: well not if he, reverts the `index.html` to `index.html.original` first to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be your 3rd party software editor has created the file as backup and renamed it as `index.html.save`. It could be a temporary file created by the editor each time you hit Ctrl+S (save).